# Is it possible to fetch/parse JSON data from one component to a different rendered/dynamic route? (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactJS and just started learning it for a coding assignment, but I am stuck on this one problem. I created an api in a component that FETCHes photo and photo album data from the online JSON prototyping website, and I want to use that data to display on a user page (only photos and albums related to that specific user/userID). The user page is a dynamic child component of the parent component (the home page). here is what it looks like so far

This is for the JSON data. I call it apiData

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class apiData extends Component {
    state = {
        photos: [],
        albums: [],
        isLoading: false
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData = async () => {
        const photos = await fetch(
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
        );
        const albums = await fetch(
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums"
        );
        const photoData = await photos.json();
        const albumData = await albums.json();
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, photos: photoData, albums: albumData});
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <p> dataObject={this.state.results}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the rendered/dynamic route. currently, I am using 
`const userPhoto = apiData.photos.find((userPhoto) =>{` 
to try to access the API, but I get an error that says

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

(keep in mind, these 2 components are coded on the same .js file)

```
    const userPhotoPage = ({match}) => {
    const userPhoto = apiData.photos.find((userPhoto) =>{
        return parseInt(match.params.id) == userPhoto.id
    })

    return <>
        {match.isExact && <>
            <h1>{userPhoto.title}</h1>
            <p>image = {userPhoto.url}</p>
            </>}
        </>
    }
```

I want my userPhotoPage function to successfully access the data from apiData, so I can manipulate it and add data to the photo page, but I'm not sure if this is possible? If I need to provide more information I'll gladly give it!

Comment: The way you are accessing data from apiData component is not proper. Take a look at this https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component on how to pass data/props to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to access the find method on an undefined object. First off, the .find() method is an iterator on arrays. I tried fetching the data from your JSON photos API but for some reason, it's hanging on this end. I'm not sure if that API actually returns an array. I would look into that first. Next, even if it returns an array and your able to chain the find method on it you're still left with the issue of function scope. The photo objects is scoped to/private your loadData async funtion. You will not be able to access it outside of the function.